# Firefox built in play and pause button

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video

I made a play button for the whole screen of my website video so it can play and pause easily in a chrome browser. Since I made this, the video will not play in Firefox because Firefox already has a built-in play and pause button.

How can I turn off the Firefox built-in play and pause buttons in my code?  I am guessing this can somehow be done in Javascript.

#### Javascript play and pause:

```
$(function(){
  $(".video-js").on("click", function(){
    if(this.paused) {
       $(this).trigger('play')
    } else if(this.played) {
        $(this).trigger('pause')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you post your code for us to look at?

Comment: Just posted the code that makes the screen on chrome browser to play and pause.

Comment: what if you add a onclick on window and look if the player is playing, if not,start it. window.onclick=function(){//logic here;};

Comment: I know that my code is working fine because I put a console.log("play") and a console.log("pause") in the function.  Firefox is recognizing the action because the words "play" and "pause" show in the console when I click the video. What is happening is that right when I hit my play button, Firefoxe's built-in controls pause the video right after.  So the video is playing for less than a split second and then pausing.

Comment: So my question is how to disable that Firefox feature while still keeping the code that I wrote.

Comment: @HealyFuess Can you also post your HTML? It has just as much bearing as the javascript.